# Method chaining results in unchecked call warning

Tags: java, methods, warnings, chaining, unchecked

I have got the following interface which is implemented by the following class. For this class, I would like to be able to use method chaining, which is why I added a "return this" at the end of the addFilter() method:

```
public interface IFilteredDataService<B extends Bean> extends IDataService<B>
{
    FilteredDataService applyFilter(Predicate<B> filter);
}

public class FilteredDataService<B extends Bean> implements IFilteredDataService<B>
{
    @Override
    public FilteredDataService addFilter(Predicate<B> filter)
    {
        filters.add(filter);
        return this;
    }
}
```

When I use the addFilter() method in the following way, everything is fine:

```
someInstance.addFilter(foo);
someInstance.addFilter(bar);
```

When I use the method chaining like this:

```
someInstance.addFilter(foo).addFilter(bar);
```

it still works fine, but I get the following warning:

```
Unchecked call to 'addFilter(Predicate<B>)' as a member of raw type 'FilteredDataService'.
```

I was not able to figure out why this happens and how to remove it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the generic information in your return value, returning a *raw* (non-generic) `FilteredDataService`.

Use `public FilteredDataService<B> addFilter(Predicate<B> filter)` to keep the generics.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to use generic and chain this method, you have to create **fully generic method** (include returning) as Kayaman wrote. And take a look at what you getting:

> Unchecked call to 'addFilter(Predicate)' as a member of raw type 'FilteredDataService'.

In simple translation: You are calling method which should accept generic param (addFilter(Predicate filter)) but you are sending nongeneric param during chaining (return this; = FilteredDataService -> Non-Generic).
Just for clarify :o)